# JxBrowser. Loading local recources

Tags: jxbrowser

Is it possible in JxBrowser to reference resources (images, scripts, etc) from class path or local files?
Tried several approaches:

```
<img src="image.png"/>
<img src="file://image.png"/>
<img src="file://full/path/image.png"/>
```

none of these were working

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the following Chromium switches:

```
BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches(        
"--disable-web-security",        
"--allow-file-access-from-files");
```

As for the approach, this is an example of the working one:

```
<img src="file:///C:/folder/0001-1.jpg"/>
```